# underscorejs _find with arrays of objects

Tags: json, angularjs

i'm quite new to underscorejs and i tr to find a value within the following json file stored on the web (http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/poona.json)

```
{
    "joueur": [
      {
        "civilite": "M.",
        "nom": "HURAT",
        "prenom": "Florent",
        "instance": "Badminton Club De Lyon",
        "licence": "00403566",
        "hebdoSimpleClassementId": "R5",
        "hebdoSimpleCote": "128.00",
        "hebdoDoubleClassementId": "R4",
        "hebdoDoubleCote": "475.98",
        "hebdoMixteClassementId": "R5",
        "hebdoMixteCote": "203.40"
      },
      {
        "civilite": "M.",
        "nom": "IHUEL",
        "prenom": "Philipe",
        "instance": "Badminton Club De Lyon",
        "licence": "06468814",
        "hebdoSimpleClassementId": "D7",
        "hebdoSimpleCote": "32.00",
        "hebdoDoubleClassementId": "R6",
        "hebdoDoubleCote": "78.29",
        "hebdoMixteClassementId": "R6",
        "hebdoMixteCote": "69.72"
      },
      {
        "civilite": "M.",
        "nom": "ISTRE",
        "prenom": "Jacques",
        "instance": "Badminton Club De Lyon",
        "licence": "00258046",
        "hebdoSimpleClassementId": "P2",
        "hebdoSimpleCote": "2.00",
        "hebdoDoubleClassementId": "P1",
        "hebdoDoubleCote": "4.74",
        "hebdoMixteClassementId": "P2",
        "hebdoMixteCote": "2.00"
      },
      {
        "civilite": "M.",
        "nom": "JACQUEMET",
        "prenom": "Mathieu",
        "instance": "Badminton Club De Lyon",
        "licence": "06910375",
        "hebdoSimpleClassementId": "P2",
        "hebdoSimpleCote": "2.70",
        "hebdoDoubleClassementId": "P3",
        "hebdoDoubleCote": "0.00",
        "hebdoMixteClassementId": "P3",
        "hebdoMixteCote": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "civilite": "Mlle",
        "nom": "JACQUEMIN",
        "prenom": "Alice",
        "instance": "Badminton Club De Lyon",
        "licence": "00273896",
        "hebdoSimpleClassementId": "R4",
        "hebdoSimpleCote": "385.83",
        "hebdoDoubleClassementId": "N3",
        "hebdoDoubleCote": "657.08",
        "hebdoMixteClassementId": "R4",
        "hebdoMixteCote": "300.00"
      }
    ]
}
```

I use the following factory to proceed :

```
baclyApp.factory('poonaFactory',function($http){
  var factory ={};
  $http.get("http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/readPoona.php").success(function(data)
  // $http.get("php/readPoona.php").success(function(data)
  {
    factory.joueurs = data;
    console.log(factory.joueurs);
    }).error(function(status) {
    alert("pas d accès réseau") 
    });

return {
        list: function(){
            return factory;
        },
        find: function(num){
            return _.find(factory.joueurs, function(item) {return item.licence == num});
        }       
        }
});
```

and call is like this (debugging purpose i hardcoded the value) :

```
console.log(poonaFactory.find("06468814"));
```

Any advice is welcome !
Thx

Comment: What errors are you seeing? In what way is it not working? Are you calling `find` before the `$http.get(...)` promise has succeeded?

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting any errors? If so, where?

Comment: @aidan : yes, i do a console.log of poonafactory and it works.

Comment: @Preethi : Sorry, my question is that i don't get any result, got undefined return

Answer (score 0):

You need `return _.find(factory.joueur, ...)` instead of `return _.find(factory.joueurs, ...)`

;)